# How to pipe the result of 'date' command to 'mv' command

Tags: shell, rename, pipe

I want to rename my file to the current timestamp.I know how to get the current timestamp("date +%s") but how can I pipe it to 'mv' command?

Comment: So you can start to sort this out in your head, you should know part of the reason you didn't figure this out was you you were asking the wrong question. What you needed was, "Using the output of one command as arguments for another." Depending on the scenario this can be done with the `$()` and back-tick operators. This is distinctly different from "piping" data from one program to another. In the case that you had output that you wanted to convert to arguments, you could also use `xargs` to execute another command with arguments taken from stdin or `read` to just make a variable out of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use something like this (`bash`):

```
mv myfile myfile.$(date +%s)
```

Or alternatively:

```
mv myfile myfile.`date +%s`
```

if your shell doesn't do the `$(command)` thing.

Comment: Thanks.both work for me.I copy and pasted the second because I can't type "`".How do I type this character?

Comment: Depends on your keyboard... `AltGr+7` on a "normal" French AZERTY keyboard. On English layouts it's often on the top-left key (just above `tab`, on the left of `1`). Its ASCII code is 0x60 (96 dec.).

Comment: One should emphasize that these are backticks around the date command, not ordinary single quotes.

Comment: I think the importance of back-ticks over single quotes can probably be assumed on a unix site, but it should probably be noted that `$()` syntax is the newer and preferred format for this operation.