# How to feed the results of date command into grep to filter results of another command

Tags: shell, grep, pipe, date

I need to use the result of a formatted date command (date +"%m/%d") as the grep filter to filter the results of another command that will display alerts on a system so that I only see alerts from the given day.

Lets say alertcommand gives the alert readout in the console.
I know I can do `alertcommand | grep 8/10` to get the logs from today, but I want to be able to feed `date +"%m/%d"`into that so that I don't have to specify the date each time I run it, but I can't figure out how to link it into one single command (preferably without having to create temp files or anything as this will be run on customer hardware).

I looked at [this question that was similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/how-to-pipe-the-result-of-date-command-to-mv-command), but couldn't figure out how to make it work the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, just use something like `alertcommand | grep $(date +"%m/%d")`

`$()` executes a command in a subshell and returns the output of the command as string. Alternatively you can enclose the command with backticks to the same effect.

Comment: This worked, seems I was just missing the format of how to write it out from the other question I noted. I prefer to use $() as it is the more modern implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply assign the output of your date command to another variable, and use that as an argument:

```
myDateVariable=`date +"%m/%d"`
alertcommand | grep $myDateVariable
```

This way, you could re-use the date value in the future and also debug any intermediate steps

Comment: Not as useful to me as a single line command, but still a valid method.

Comment: You can always separate them via a semicolon. For example, you could say 
`myDateVariable=\`date +"%m/%d"\`; alertcommand | grep $myDateVariable`

Answer (score 0):

In FreeBSD's shell csh I can't use both of yours methods.

1)

```
cat /var/log/exim/mainlog | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
Illegal variable name.
```

2)

```
d=`date +%Y-%m-%d`;cat /var/log/exim/mainlog|grep $d
d=2011-11-13: Command not found.
```

But I can use directly backticked code like this:

```
cat /var/log/exim/mainlog | grep `date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Comment: `csh` is harmful, stop using it. http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/